# Amazon SP-API get shipping addresses for all orders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

In the old MWS "getOrders" api call, there was in the response a field for each order named "shippindAddress" which I could use to create my shipping labels.

In the new SP-API in the getOrders there is no such field. Instead you can get the shipping address via "/orders/v0/orders/{orderId}/address ". But you should call this api for each order (>100) and the rate is set for 1 per second.. So for 100 orders I will have to wait over 1.5 mins to get all addresses.

Is there a possibility to get all order with shipping addresses ? Or to increase the request limit ?

Answer (score 2):

you should use restricted data token for buyer info and detailed address info, instead of "/orders/v0/orders/{orderId}/address" endpoint